# MarkerView in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Can we add `MarkerView` to `PieChart` and `HorizontalBarChart` from [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

I did try adding the `MarkerView` to the pie chart as the following:

```
TooltipView tooltipView = new TooltipView(context,R.layout.tooltip_layout, metadata);
chart.setMarkerView(tooltipView);
```

But when I click on the slice of the pie chart, no `MarkerView` is shown.
Also, the same thing happens for horizontal bar chart.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, probably you could just answer.

Comment: I have the same issue with `HorizontalBarChart`. I'm using v2.1.3 of MPAndroidChart library. My implementation of custom `MarkerView` is correct, because if I simply change `HorizontalBarChart` to `BarChart` everything works as expected. Once I return `HorizontalBarChart` back, no markers are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, `PieChart` and `HorizontalBarChart` do not support `MarkerView`. Nevertheless, this is high on my list and will probably be added soon in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your question, but here are some things to check:

- Ensure that ToolTipView extends `MarkerView`
- Also make sure that you implement the `refreshContent()`, `getXOffSet()` and `getYOffSet()` methods.

That should allow you to view the marker view item.

I am not sure what the metadata value you are entering does, as the refresh method should allow you access the currently selected value and its data.